# Tool for generating Feature Class including field names/type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing

I am trying to build a tool that will generate a feature class and then populate the fields with the correct column name and format based off a CSV file.

Has anyone had any luck doing this before?

I'm looking for model or code examples if anyone happens to have anything similar.

Has anyone seen any tutorial documents online that do this type of request?

I am using Arc 10.2. ESRI:Arcpy

Comment: What you really want to do is define the fields at the time of creation (vice creating a nominal feature class with just objectid and geometry, then adding columns one by one).  It's probably important to note that Excel is notoriously bad at table definition, since it isn't a database.

Comment: Thanks Vince but I'm trying to automate this process. I have too many feature classes and fields to do this manually. Changed Excel to CSV also....thanks!

Comment: So you are after something that will read a csv file and create  the feature class?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I end up with something that creates a feature class and then uses data in the csv file to generate the field names and type for the feature class or if it should be something that will populate field values and types for already existing feature classes.

Comment: What programming/scripting language are you intending to use? Possibilities include Esri: arcpy, ArcObjects in C#, VB.net, C++, OGR: python, C#/VB.net, C++, ANSI C, Ruby, Perl,... (there may be others I don't know about). Shapely in Python... and these are only the major players. Pick one from the list that you're interested in and edit your question to include the appropriate tag. If you can't narrow it down your question risks being too broad and is likely to be closed, neither of us wants that so it's in your best interest to specify.

Comment: Cool, arcpy, a few of us know a bit about that. Now as for the data, can you include a sample. It's not hard to read a CSV file and generate points.. getting the fields right is another story. Are you intending to know the field types or poll the CSV to see what's in each column and derive the type from there? Or is it that all the fields will be text or number (int/long/double).. that is, there has to be a reason why you want to script this and Make XY event layer isn't suitable for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hi, ^Nebula93^,

For the [Create Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-feature-class.htm) and [Add Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm) tools, there are a few parameters you have to sort out either in your CSV or in the script in order to make the tool abstract and generalizable like you want.

For instance for your feature class, you need a variable for what geometry type is it (*Point*, *Polygon*?) and what coordinate system is it in (*WGS84*, *NAD83 USA Contiguous*?).

For you CSV table, each column will also have to represent a parameter for the fields you want to create, for instance the *Field Name*, *Field Alias*, *Field Length*, etc.

Once you build the scaffolding/structure for how the parameters will be read, the actual implementation isn't too hard.

Here's an example of a script that does the trick. You have to build a skeleton tool in the toolbox that takes as parameters:

1. The CSV Table (Type: File, Direction: Input, Filter: "csv")
2. Output Feature Class (Type: Feature Class, Direction: Output)
3. Geometry Type (Type: String, Direction: Input, Filter: Value List[POINT, MULTIPOINT, POLYLINE, POLYGON]
4. Coordinate System (Type: Spatial Reference)

[image: Tool Parameters]
[image: Tool Dialog Box]

Then build the code described above. Looks something like this. The dictionary **kwarg unpacking (thanks @dmahr) and comments are superfluous, but it demonstrates the logic of the script and how someone less experienced in Python can easily tweak a parameter.

```
__author__ = "John K. Tran"
__contact__ = "jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu"
__credits__ = "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155497/tool-for-generating-feature-class-including-field-names-type"

import arcpy
import csv
import os

arcpy.SetProgressor("default", "Starting script...")

csvtable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Your CSV template.
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # The output feature class.
geometrytype = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # The geometry type of the output feature class.
spatialref = arcpy.GetParameter(3) # The coordinate system of the output feature class.

# Create the feature class.
arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Creating feature class")
# You can tweak these CreateFeatureclass_management parameters before calling the function.
CreateFeatureClassParameters = {"out_path" : os.path.dirname(fc),
                                "out_name" : os.path.basename(fc),
                                "geometry_type" : geometrytype,
                                "template" : None,
                                "has_m" : "DISABLED",
                                "has_z" : "DISABLED",
                                "spatial_reference" : spatialref,
                                "config_keyword" : None,
                                "spatial_grid_1" : None,
                                "spatial_grid_2" : None,
                                "spatial_grid_3" : None}

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(**CreateFeatureClassParameters)

# Read the CSV table and store some header information in a dictionary.
arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Reading CSV Table")
csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")
f = open(csvtable, "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, "xls")
header = reader.next()
headerdict = dict()
for index, value in enumerate(header):
    headerdict[value] = index

# Create a field for each row in the CSV, based on the header information obtained earlier.
for row in reader:
    arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Adding Field {0}".format(row[headerdict["Field Name"]]))
    # You can tweak these AddField_management parameters before calling the function.
    AddFieldParameters = {"in_table" : fc,
                          "field_name" : row[headerdict["Field Name"]],
                          "field_type" : row[headerdict["Field Type"]],
                          "field_precision" : None,
                          "field_scale" : None,
                          "field_length" : row[headerdict["Field Length (If Type=TEXT)"]],
                          "field_alias" : row[headerdict["Field Alias"]],
                          "field_is_nullable" : "NULLABLE",
                          "field_is_required" : "NON_REQUIRED",
                          "field_domain" : None}
    arcpy.AddField_management(**AddFieldParameters)

# Finish off the script.
f.close()
arcpy.ResetProgressor()
```

Lastly, since the tool reads a CSV for passing inputs in AddField_management, the CSV could look something like this:

```
Field Name,Field Type,Field Length (If Type=TEXT),Field Alias
The,TEXT,50,John
Great,FLOAT,,Paul
Seafarer,SHORT,,Jones
```

FYI, the ESRI tool information pages are indispensable. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I should also mention, if you are iterating through several **feature classes** and each feature class has the same fields as the last one, it's more efficient to pass a previous feature class as a "template" (adjust `"template" : None,`) rather than add the fields from scratch each time.

Comment: John...THANKS!!! Haven't had time to run this yet....but your feedback looks fantastic!!!

Comment: Yep, feel free to check it off as the correct answer if it works ;)

Comment: John, thanks again for your help!! I have one line of code that is hosing me up. f = open(csvtable, 'r') That keeps erroring out on me. How am I suppse to populate that line?  I keep getting invalid mode ('r') or filename.

Comment: No, you need to open the CSV file in _read_ mode, which is what the "r" represents. Can you send me your code, CSV table and complete error dialog @Nebula93? `jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu`

Comment: Fantastic Code!! I appreciate your help sir!!!